# Difference between gyro sensor and compass sensor

Tags: technic, 3rd-party

Does the HiTechnic compass perform the same function as the gyro sensor? I have been trying to find out the difference.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't personally used the HiTechnic sensors, but the difference between a gyroscope and a compass is that one measures **absolute orientation** and the other measures **change in orientation**.

The compass measures absolute orientation via a magnetometer that measures the effect of the Earth's magnetic field on the sensor. The gyro sensor uses some form of [MEMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems) to detect changes in orientation. The compass also only works in two dimensions, while the gyro likely operates in all three dimensions of orientation.

You might also be interested in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/36591/6359) from electronics.se which includes more detail than mine and also compares accelerometers to compasses and gyros.